# Error 500 in Woocommerce editing old orders

Tags: woocommerce

When I try to edit an old order from the Woocommerce backend, the screen is incompletely loaded.

You see the header data of the order, but you can not see the detail of the order.

Using the browser development tools, you see this error:

```
GET https://www.xyxyxyxxyxyxyx.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=7734&action=edit 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Some help? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an error on a plugin. The error was only in production environment, so the debug option in Test did not show any error.

I use the following configuration to debug in Production:

```
if ('MY_IP_ADDRESS' == $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) {
    define('WP_DEBUG', true);
} else {
    define('WP_DEBUG', false);   
}
```